# mod_rewrite rule working on localhost (MAMP) but not on GoDaddy linux hosting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a mod_rewrite rule to show 'image.php?id=x' to people visiting 'image/x'

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^image/([^/.]+)/?$ image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This works great on a MAMP localhost but gives me a 404 on linux server (GoDaddy).
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The files are all in place on the server so I can't figure out why this is an issue.

Any thought?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^image/([^/.]+)$ image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Or try without the RewriteBase:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^image/([^/.]+)$ image.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Or avoid GoDaddy. Just kidding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it was the RewriteBase that was throwing it. I honestly can't wait to move over to FatCow hosting. GoDaddy drives me crazy.